# React app form data not being inserted to mysql table

Tags: reactjs, axios, sequelize.js

I am trying to connect mysql table to react form via axios. React app runs on port 8081 and mysql server on 8080. Data is being added to mysql table when api tested in postman but fail whenever I try it through react form. I am assuming there is some error in my react app so posting its code, if you guys need anything please let me know.

react form

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import devicedataservice from "../services/services"

class CreateProject extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state={
                serialno:'',
                brand:'',
                modelname:'',
                submitted:false
            };
        this.onChangeSerialno=this.onChangeSerialno.bind(this);
        this.onChangeBrand=this.onChangeBrand.bind(this);
        this.onChangeModelName=this.onChangeModelName.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    
   onChangeSerialno(e){
       this.setState({
           serialno:e.target.value
       });
   }
   onChangeBrand(e){
       this.setState({
           brand:e.target.value
       });
   }
   onChangeModelName(e){
       this.setState({
           modelname:e.target.value
       });
   }
   handleSubmit(e){
      
       var data={
           serialno:this.state.serialno,
           brand:this.state.brand,
           modelname:this.state.modelname
       };
      
  
      devicedataservice.create(data)
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
            
            serialno:response.data.serialno,
            brand:response.data.brand,
            modelname:response.data.modelname,
  
            submitted: true
          });
        
        })
        .catch(e => {
         
        });
    }
  
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container ">
                    <form className="white">
                        <h1>
                            <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create Project</h5>
                           
                            <div className="input-field">
                                <label htmlFor="serialno">Serial Number</label>
                                <input  id="serialno" value={this.state.serialno} type ="text" name="serialno" onChange={this.onChangeSerialno}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="input-field">
                                <label htmlFor="brand">Brand</label>
                                <input  id="brand" value={this.state.brand} type ="text" name="brand" onChange={this.onChangeBrand}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="input-field">
                                <label htmlFor="modelname">Model Name</label>
                                <input  id="modelname" value={this.state.modelname} type ="text" name="modelname" onChange={this.onChangeModelName}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="input-field">
                                <button onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="btn blue lighten-1 z-depth-0">Add Project</button>
                            </div>  
                        </h1>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default CreateProject
```

services.js

```
import http from "../http-common";

class DeviceDataService {
  create(data) {
    return http.post(`/devices`, data);
  }
  
  getAll() {
    return http.get("/devices");
  }

  get(serialno) {
    return http.get(`/devices/${serialno}`);
  }

 

  update(serialno, data) {
    return http.put(`/devices/${serialno}`, data);
  }

  delete(serialno) {
    return http.delete(`/devices/${serialno}`);
  }

  deleteAll() {
    return http.delete(`/devices`);
  }

}

export default new DeviceDataService();
```

axios(http-common.js)

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

Comment: on your browser, check out the network tab in the developer options area, what it says ?

Comment: @Ali Im sorry I am little confused, I am using firefox and the network tab just opens the network monitor, do want to know something specific?